# disable a wp javascript on live website, but not on wp-admin page

Tags: wp-admin, javascript

I have a wp javascript, **wp-embed.min.js**, disabled on my WordPress theme by adding this sample code to my theme's function.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
```

The problem is that the javascript is disabled everywhere, including in the wp-admin page, and one of the plugins I want to use requires it to work.

Is there a way to disable a specific wordpress javascript only on the live website, but not on wp-admin pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a simple [is_admin()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) check before dequeuing your script like below:

**Code**:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {

   if ( !is_admin() )
       wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
   }

}
```